# Increasing the Upload Limit of my PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple PHP script. Its used to upload users into the joomla tables. Basically it uploads users into joomla three main tables.

The PHP uploader sript works fine when the CSV is about 80MB to 100 MB.

It does not work or just nothing happens when the file size is 500MB or above.

How do i make the PHP script work to upload the CSV files of over 500 MB?

Do i actually change something in my PHP.ini settings or is there something else i could
add in the script itself.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the .htcaccess file add the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
```

in php.ini add:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
```

Comment: Are we fans of plagiarism or just forgetting to link to the source at drupal.org?

Comment: For two lines in .htaccess and two lines in php.ini? Are you kidding me?

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg : let me try

Comment: How would that be plagiarism these are facts not creative work

Comment: @Matt using your logic anyone who come to the this site and uses code from it is guilty of plagiarism, lol. So i got it from a source which i had bookmarked big deal..!

Comment: @GershonHerczeg my intent was to be snarky, not accusatory. Text isn't the best format for that, though, I suppose.

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg : After making the changes do i have to restart mysql?

Comment: No @sony_CO, you dont need to restart it.

Comment: @Matt no worries, sarcastic / snarky remarks are often misinterpreted in written format.

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg : What if it were more than 500MB?.. i mean about 1GB? The i should mak it 1024M ?

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg : After adding those lines in the .htacess file...i got an internal server (500) error..

Comment: it worked though..through a change in the php.ini settings.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: i already tried ini_set()..let me check also the htaccess file as per Gershon Herczeg

Comment: Can't change uploads limits via ini_set(). The script is executedly only AFTER the upload is completed - if the limit is too low, the upload is killed before the ini_set() is ever seen. This has to be done at the php.ini/.htaccess level

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue long time ago with rails and mysql,

You have to consider 3 things when you want to upload a file:

- Max upload file in PHP
- Be sure that MySQL will save a big file.
- Your browser will lost connection after a while uploading a file to your database if it don't receive any answer from the server.

I think that You handled the first 2, but to handle the 3rd probably you will need a upload progress bar to keep the session active.  Actually you need some AJAX to keep the server and the client "talking" meanwhile the file still uploading.

Comment: yeah..let me see if can become a AJAX developer in a day :-)